# What is $\sum\limits_{i=1}^{2012} b_{4i}$?

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations, sums-of-squares, parity

Let $a_k$ be the number of ordered 10-tuples $(x_1, x_2,\ldots,x_{10})$ of nonnegative integers such that
$x_1^2
+ x_2^2
 +\cdots+ x
_{10}^2 = k.$
Let 
$$
b_k=
\begin{cases}
0 & \text{if}\,\, a_k\,\, \text{is even}\\ 
1 & \text{if}\,\, a_k\,\,\text{is odd}
\end{cases}
$$

Find $\sum_\limits{i=1}^{2012}b_{4i}$.

Any help is appreciated.

For those curious, the solution which I have trouble comprehending is item 1 from the [CHMMC-2012 Spring Tiebreakers](http://chmmc.caltech.edu/archives/2012spring/chmmc2012-tb-sol.pdf).

I'm having trouble understanding the first part of the solution:

> ...We can pair each 10-tuple with its reverse without changing the
>   parity of the number of solutions. Only those 10-tuples which are palindromes are unpaired,
>   so $x_i = x_{11−i}$ and so we can consider the following equation without changing the $b_k$ sequence:
>   $2x_1^2
>  + 2x_2^2
>  + 2x_3^2 + 2x_4^2
>  + 2x_5^2
>  = k$

I know this is a basic question, but why can you assume $x_i = x_{11−i}$ and how does it not change parity of number of solutuins to the equation?

Comment: We are not "assume $x_i = x_{11-i}$". We are pairing up solutions $ (x_ i)$ and $(x_i ')$ when $ x_i = x'_{11-i}$.We can then discard both solutions and not affect the parity of the number of solutions.

Comment: The best practice would have been to edit the first post. Please do so next time.